# Managing Web Site Users with Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

I have created a website from Visual Studio. 
And my login control are built in the masterpage.master.

I also have a `userprofile.aspx` which denied anonymous user from accessing. I had added the access rule which restricted the whole Members folder which inside included `userprofile.aspx` when the page was view my annoymous user.

However when I run the website, and click on the menu control to direct me to `userprofile.aspx`, this error occured :

The resource cannot be found.

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of
>   its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.

By default, the access rule directed to `"login.aspx"`. But I do not have this file.. Is there any way which I can changed to destination url which could direct an anonymous user to the`masterpage.master` file and not `login.aspx`??

Comment: Hi, Jakub. Thanks for your reminding! (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You control the destination url through the `web.config` file

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="member_login.aspx"
    defaultUrl="index.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Set `loginUrl` to the desired URL.

You can redirect to a `page`, not `master page`, btw.

Comment: I have added in the code, however there's an warning message, a blue curly lines under the code - forms. Which stated that "The element 'system.web' has invalid child element 'forms'.

Comment: You've missed `authentication` element

Comment: Hi, what you mean by missing the authentication element??

Comment: After you edited your web.config file `<forms>` element ended up under `<system.web>` element. `<forms>` element must be a child of `<authentication>` element, which in turn should inside `<system.web>` element. Read about the structure of `web.config` file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, find the following section on your web.config:

```
<forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
protection="All"
timeout="30"
name=".ASPXAUTH" 
path="/"
requireSSL="false"
slidingExpiration="true"
defaultUrl="default.aspx"
cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"
enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
</authentication>
</system.web>
```